# css table center not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've centered a table using the following:

```
table{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

It works great on Google Chrome but not at all on Firefox, any ideas?
Should I wrap the table in a Div and use a specific ID for it?

P.S I didn't use -webkit- on it. If I used -webkit-, I made sure to also add -moz-

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9pA6/)

Here is a link for you guys to examine:
[you can see for yourself](http://ogjewels.co.il/content/gallery/Buy-Bracelets-1.html)

Comment: Please post the code here and if possible an example on jsFiddle.net.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can only say ['no-repro'](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QwYhx/), on Chromium 18, Firefox14 and Opera 12.

Comment: I've added a link so you could see it.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox 14.0.1 here.

Comment: just upgraded to 14.0.1, not showing well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS

Add this to your CSS file:

```
header
{
    float:none!important
    /* or remove float:right; in your current CSS file */
}
#nav
{
    background:none;
    float:right
}
#tb
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1080px;
    border-spacing:0;
    border:0;
    border-collapse:collapse
}
.clearfix:after
{
    clear:both;
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden
}
.clearfix
{
    display:block;
    zoom:1
}
```

### HTML

And in your HTML code change:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
```

to:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul id="nav" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm missing Tbody tag, might that be the problem?

Comment: It's wrapped using <section> with an ID, should I also add div, I thought Firefox handles html5 nicely.

Comment: can you give further explanation how you managed to see what the problem was? for future errors like this.

Comment: Honestly, I just removed different parts from your source code, and when I removed the `header` everything was working fine. :) And then I just looked at your CSS code, and went on from there. BTW, the problem was with your `floats`. When you use `float`, then just wrap a `<div class="clearfix">` around those elements, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on how/where your table is nested, you need either to center the content in your parent container or to center the page body, or add `position:absolute;` to the table css.

Comment: using position:absolute; ruined the display on Chrome ;-/